# My express req.sessions get saved as undefined in Express v4

Tags: node.js, express, session-variables, express-session

My express V4 app doesn't give me the correct value of the sessions instead just returns `undefined`. My app was structured and built using express-generator and this is my app.js file.

```
var express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
routes = require('./routes/index'),
app = express(),
compression = require('compression'),
session = require('express-session');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('view cache', true);

app.enable('trust proxy');

app.use(session({
    secret: "Share3na Network!195",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true, httpOnly: true }
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', routes);
```

And these are the routes the take the session value and send it back.

```
router.get('/getmask', function(req,res){
    res.send(req.session.mask);
});

//GET the mask during event body load
router.get('/sendmask', function(req,res){
    req.session.mask = striptags(emojiStrip(req.query.m));
});
```

In another route when I append the requests' IP address with the session value: `req.ip() + req.session.mask`, what gets saved in the database is "123.456.789undefined"

Comment: Although `secure: true` is a recommended option, It requires an https-enabled website, i.e., HTTPS is necessary for secure cookies. If secure is set, and you access your site over HTTP, the cookie will not be set.

Comment: i think you should use cookie-parser module
https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser

Comment: @dNitro I know, my web app is already on HTTPS

Comment: @AsifSaeed I thought too and that's what I did at first but the `express-session` middleware now doesn't depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the session values after modification. The documentation for the same can be seen in [the README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#sessionsavecallback) of the package.

```
//GET the mask during event body load
router.get('/sendmask', function(req,res){
    req.session.mask = striptags(emojiStrip(req.query.m));
    req.session.save();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunetly it doesn't work. Still undefined. Any other tricks I can do?

Comment: @TonyLee How are you accessing the `/sendmask` path?

Comment: Via AJAX. On window load it sends a number to that route and then I want that number to be saved in the session "mask"

Comment: Does the `req.query.m` exist? For it to be available, you need the path to be `/sendmask?m=something`